# Free plugin similar to myeclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, myeclipse

One of the best plug-in and most comprehensive ones I found for Java EE and Java web development is [myeclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com/). However, it's not free. Is there any free version of a similar plug-in that contains all these features?

Comment: *All* the features? No. *Many* of the features? Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I think that Eclipse Java EE edition + JBoss tools covers most of the core things that MyEclipse offers.

We have used MyEclipse for years, simply because WTP (the main extra plug-ins in Eclipse for Java EE) was rather horrible by itself. MyEclipse build on the foundation of a heavily modified WTP and fixed many bugs. Equally important was that there was a tech support forum staffed by apparently actual developers, who easily understood the issues raised.

In later years WTP improved considerably and offered the core value of MyEclipse (starting/debugging a server, hot/incrementally deploying artifacts, editing JSP/Facelets). So MyEclipse then seemed to refocus on its Pulse platform, which was something I personally didn't need. Combine this with the fact that the support forum was increasingly being staffed by people who didn't seem to be developers ("I'll escalate the issue with management" was a typical response) and not many people in our team felt the need to stay with MyEclipse.

JBoss tools is a rather loose collection of individual plug-ins that enhances the WTP offerings. Contrary to its name, it's not just about JBoss specific tooling. Many of its features are universally useable (like e.g. the improved Facelets editor).

A disadvantage of JBoss tools is that it runs nearly exactly 1 version out-of-sync with Eclipse. Meaning that at about the same time JBoss tools for Eclipse version X goes GA, Eclipse X+1 is released (but MyEclipse always had the exact same disadvantage).

Of course if you actually need what Pulse offers and your company digs commercial support, then MyEclipse might still be the better choice. So with all things, it depends on what you exactly need.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe should ask about specific features/plugins. The wtp editions is a great place to start: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/

Also read this blog post.
http://www.venukb.com/2006/08/20/install-eclipse-plugins-the-easy-way/